# Java App Crash under OSX

Tags: java, macos, exception

I am writing a network application on Java and I have come across a weird bug. The application is sending text between two clients.Some works of the text are highlighted. When that happens I get an OSX crash report.This is some of it :

```
Crashed Thread:  19  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001070ba000-00000001070c2000 [   32K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Application Specific Information:
objc[1293]: garbage collection is OFF

Java information:
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=7fff96a7b698

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02-402 mixed mode macosx-amd64)
```

Also in the IDE (netbeans) this message appears : `Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x7fff96a7b698`

Finally sometimes when I reproduce the exception in a different way this exception is thrown in the IDE :

```
2012-03-20 23:15:40.025 java[1071:e503] -[__NSCFNumber ctFontRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fad326dd490
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Non-Java exception raised, not handled! (Original problem: -[__NSCFNumber ctFontRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fad326dd490)
```

I asked a friend to test this application on his windows machine and it turned out it worked (Although I am not 100% sure that he followed the steps correctly for causing the bug).

Any suggestions as to what might cause this , or possible solutions ?
If you need some more info let me know.

Comment: You need to show some code or all that follows will be guessing.

Comment: The code wouldn't really help unless if I send whole classes which would still not really help because there are a lot of stuff done by open source libraries.. I know I can't expect too much help just hoping someone got across same errors.

Comment: This looks like a seg fault in `NSCFNumber`, a private class inside `NSNumber`... but this would be ObjectiveC land, not Java. Are you using SWT or some Cocoa bindings for Java? This might be a problem with an outdated third party library calling into ObjectiveC.

Comment: From the library website it seems like its written in Java. I tested my self on a windows machine and there was no crash and application run normally..

Comment: You didn't mention which library?

Comment: Its RSyntaxTextArea. Also I use JGroups but the problem only appears with highlighting of keywords.

Comment: Is there any *stacktrace* when you get that RuntimeException in your IDE?

Comment: No only 'Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x7fff96a7b698' appears .

Comment: Is there any chance this has something to do with me using SSD?

Comment: Unlikey related to SSD. Judging from the `ctFontRef` and the fact that it's happening on the AWT event queue thread, this looks more like some AWT/Java2D call implemented on top of a non-existing ObjectiveC method.

Comment: In the application I have been using Java Deep Cloning library and somehow the way I used it caused crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was originating from the use of a deep clone library. Once I changed my code and removed this library the issue was solved.